# How can I access the name of a current library in a CL program?

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I need to use the current library name explicitly in a CL program.

```
CHGVAR &LIB *CURLIB
```

doesn't work (after this line &lib = '*curlib'). This should be simple - any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it:

RTVJOBA CURLIB(&LIB)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that a given job may not have a current library.
In which case &LIB will have a value of *NONE